# Equivalent to @JsonIdentityInfo for XML object to overcome infinite recursive loop on Spring MVC

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-data-jpa

My data model object will support both XML and JSON. Now I am able to get JSON (Accept: application/json) object but for XML (Accept: application/xml) getting below exception:
Example: [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: A cycle is detected in the object graph. This will cause infinitely deep XML: ....

I have fixed the recursive loop for JSON fixed by using @JsonIdentityInfo. But how to fix for XML. ?
My data model classes are:

Enterprise Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "enterprise")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property = "enterpriseId", scope = Enterprise.class)
public class Enterprise extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
//setters and getter for properties
}
```

Organization Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property = "organizationId", scope = Organization.class)
public class Organization extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
//setters and getter for properties
}
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot, finally found the solution.
solved the issue as below:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;
public class Organization extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
....
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy = "organizations") 
private Enterprise enterprise;
...
}
```

Thanks :)